# Transcribing the baptism of Martha Elisabeth Schweitzer in 1697 in Oberellenbach

Tags: church-records, german-language, transcriptions, kurrent, german

I'm trying to transcribe this baptism entry.  I could use some assistance fixing any errors.

[image]

```
Den 17 Mai ist Elisabeth Schweitzerin in mehrn er
hieltes kind mit Hans Jacob Breben getaufft
3. ihm der enhir Martha Elisabetttan Johannes seit
Tochter von Cunneguthas gegeben worden
```

Thr very rough Google translation that gives me is:
"On May 17th, Elisabeth Schweitzerin was baptized in several years with Hans Jacob Breben. 3. The enhir Martha Elisabetttan Johannes was given to him as the daughter of Cunneguthas."